# how to modify this python list sequentially

Tags: python, list, python-2.6

Suggestions please in Python 2.6 to convert this starting list:

```
lis = ['1','2','2','2','3','3','4','7','9']
```

into:

```
lis2 = ['1_1','2_1','2_2','2_3','3_1','3_2','4_1','7_1','9_1']
```

Note, the items are strings

Comment: Show us  your code so far.  This isn't a programming service.

Comment: Your sequence is sorted. Will it always be? If not, should the numbering be for unique values or for groups?

Comment: I was not using it as such. As a beginner I learn a lot from the examples of others to whom I am very grateful. I could not get beyond putting string frequencies into a dict with: diction={}
for char in lis:
  diction[char]=lis.count(char)

Comment: Martijn, I am trying to write a script to rename files using part of the modification date in the new file name. Since I would extract the filename and its date into a list for further processing, the files would be sorted before this.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>>
>>> lis = ['1','2','2','2','3','3','4','7','9']
>>> lis2 = []
>>> cnt = defaultdict(int)
>>> for x in lis:
...     cnt[x] += 1
...     lis2.append('{}_{}'.format(x, cnt[x]))
...
>>> lis2
['1_1', '2_1', '2_2', '2_3', '3_1', '3_2', '4_1', '7_1', '9_1']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
from itertools import groupby

['{}_{}'.format(i, count) for _, g in groupby(lis) for count, i in enumerate(g, 1)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> ['{}_{}'.format(i, count) for _, g in groupby(lis) for count, i in enumerate(g, 1)]
['1_1', '2_1', '2_2', '2_3', '3_1', '3_2', '4_1', '7_1', '9_1']
```

This uses no additional memory, but requires your groups to be distinct and sorted; if there are two runs of `2`, then each run is numbered separately.

Answer (score 0):

A twist on the `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import count

data = ['1','2','2','2','3','3','4','7','9']    
result = map(lambda L, dd=defaultdict(lambda: count(1)): '{}_{}'.format(L, next(dd[L])), data)
# ['1_1', '2_1', '2_2', '2_3', '3_1', '3_2', '4_1', '7_1', '9_1']
```